# MYSQL XDev API Javascript Select all from a table

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

I'm trying to get all the promocodes out of a table but I'm not sure what we should use for the bind parameter.  I tried '*', ' ', '%%', and '%' but the results came out undefined/no results.  Anyone know how to get all the results?

```
  router.post('/getpromocodes', function(res){
        mysqlx.getSession(stageConnectionmysqlx)
            .then(function(session){
            var promoTable = session.getSchema('exampleTable').getTable('promo')
            promoTable
                .select(['promo_code', 'promo_percentage', 'expiration_date'])
                .where('promo_code like :promo_code')
                .bind('promo_code', '*')
                .execute()
            })
            .then(function(result){
                let data = result.fetchAll()
                console.log('Here is the data', data)
                res.send(data)
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log('the following error occured: ' + err.message)
            })
            
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was where I placed my closing } and ).

The .then needs to come right after the execute. And as Rui described to pull everything from the table, do not use the .where and .bind methods.

```
router.post('/getpromocodes', function(res){
    mysqlx.getSession(stageConnectionmysqlx)
        .then(function(session){
        var promoTable = session.getSchema('exampleSchema').getTable('promo')
        promoTable
            .select(['promo_code', 'promo_percentage', 'expiration_date'])
            .execute()
            .then(function(result){
              let data = result.fetchAll()
              console.log('Here is the data', data)
              res.send(data)
        })
    })     
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log('the following error occured: ' + err.message)
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason for using the `where()` clause? In the end, the X Plugin will convert the CRUD operation into an SQL statement using `LIKE`, so you are bound by the same syntax limitations.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

In the best case scenario, you should simply just drop the `where()` clause, like the following:

```
promoTable.select(['promo_code', 'promo_percentage', 'expiration_date'])
  .execute()
```

Comment: I made the changed described above and I've added a console.log(session.inspect) into my code and there is data in the table.  (1 row for testing).   Here is what I get: `{
  auth: 'MYSQL41',
  host: '193.122.179.108',
  pooling: false,
  port: 33060,
  schema: undefined,
  socket: undefined,
  tls: false,
  user: 'robot',
  dbUser: [Getter],
  ssl: [Getter]
}
Here is the result undefined
the following error occured: Cannot read property 'fetchAll' of undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Maybe you we can move this discussion to the MySQL community Slack. That way, you should be able to provide more and better context.